# How to add virtual column in relational algebra

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra

Suppose we have table `A` and a table `B` which has foreign key referencing to `A`'s PK.

I used to perform the following query in SQL (MySQL to be exact) to select all rows and columns of `A` and an aggregation (for example SUM) of `B`s for each row of A.

```sql
SELECT A.*, 
       (
           SELECT SUM(B.value)
           from B
           WHERE B.AID = A.ID
           ) AS sum_b,
FROM A;
```

I wonder how can I add this virtual columns in relational algebra. Does the projection operator can accept a relation as its argument? If yes how would be the notation?

Comment: You can't create such virtual columns, but you can create a view instead.

Comment: What exactly is it that you can't do? Aggregation? A query doesn't "add" a column to anything, use enough words to be clear. In what way "virtual"? PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Please show what parts you are able to do. See [ask], other [Help] links & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: We can expect that moving a (scalar) (correlated) subquery from SELECT to after FROM using a JOIN in SQL is a faq. Anyway you can try to do move it yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55301503/3404097

Comment: The mentioned question was a great help though. There was a good solution with the help of joins. Thank you @philipxy

Comment: Please edit this post to be clear. Posts are forever & for other people. (And poorly received posts count towards posting limits, whether deleted or not.) If it becomes a duplicate of the link I gave then you can flag it so. Although then it won't be an algebra question, it will be SQL only. I couldn't mark this as a duplicate myself, which would give you an option to click to agree, because I already flagged as unclear. If the link Q&A helped you, please consider upvoting there.